# Pivot DataFrame but mapping values fails

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame like this one (although much bigger)

[image: Initial DataFrame]

And I want to transform/pivot it into a DataFrame with unique Barcodes as Columns and the Index as ID_Pin.
Like this

[image: Goal DataFrame]

```
def pivot_dataframe(attribute_name):
    view = input_data[["Barcode", "Component ID", "PinNumber", attribute_name]]

    index = view["Component ID"] + "_" + view["PinNumber"].astype(int).astype(str) + "_" + attribute_name
    index.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    index.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

    barcodes = view["Barcode"].drop_duplicates()
    barcodes.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

    return view.pivot_table(index=index, columns=barcodes, values=attribute_name)
```

I'm able to create the Index and the Columns as Series but the problem is that the values are not mapped correctly.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how I could map my values to the Index and Columns without looping over everything. Anyone a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
new_df = df.set_index(['ID','Pin','Barcode']).Measurement.unstack()

new_df.index = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in new_df.index]
```

Output:

```
Barcode   00   01
0_2      NaN  0.3
1_0      0.5  1.0
2_1      0.3  NaN
```

Comment: The problem is when unstacking ID/Pin are not unique anymore, and I end up with duplicate entries

Comment: In other words, you have duplicate combination of `['ID','Pin','Barcode']`? What do you want to do with duplicated data on `Measurement`?

Comment: Then my code should work as expected with no duplicates once pivoted.

Answer (score 0):

If the specific formatting of the index is not important, you could also use `pandas.pivot_table` with a multidimensional index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Barcode": ["00", "00", "01", "01"],
                   "ID": [1, 2, 0, 1],
                   "Pin": [0, 1, 2, 0],
                   "Measurment": [0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 1]})

result = pd.pivot_table(df,
                        columns="Barcode",
                        index=["ID", "Pin"],
                        values="Measurment")
```

Output:

```
>>> result

Barcode   00   01
ID Pin           
0  2     NaN  0.3
1  0     0.5  1.0
2  1     0.3  NaN
```

You can then use [pandas MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) syntax to get specific combinations of `ID` and `Pin`:

```
>>> result.loc[(0, 2)]

Barcode
00    NaN
01    0.3
```

or individual combinations of `ID`, `Pin` and `Barcode`:

```
>>> result.loc[(0, 2), "01"]
0.3
```